# Перенос текста с разрывом слов

Tags: скрипт, text, javascript, css

Здравствуйте!

Есть проблема с переносом длинных слов внутри блока. Слишком длинные слова переносятся на следующую строку и тем самым ломают всю вёрстку.

**Подскажите скрипт** который бы осуществлял перенос с разрывом слов.

Было бы идеально если бы разрыв слов осуществлялся по правилам русского языка, но в тексте присутствуют и слова на латинице!

Comment: quittance.ru/blog/index.php?category=6

Comment: Дизайнер должен предусматривать такие вещи, иначе это не дизайнер, а рисовальщик в Фотошопе. Вечно понапихают всяких «John Smith», ибо некомпетентны или ссат посмотреть как будет выглядеть «Константин Константинопольский».

Comment: А решение проблемы очень простое — поставьте overflow:hidden и ничего страшного, что некоторые длинные слова будут обрываться. А со скриптами переноса запаритесь, ну их нафиг.

Comment: @ReinRaus, Вариант не плохой..., правда нет времени разбираться, поэтому выбираю вариант предложенный @artuska! Всем СПАСИБО!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Javascript hyphenator](https://code.google.com/p/hyphenator/)

Answer (score 2):

В 2017 году более актуально будет использовать [Hyphenopoly.js](https://github.com/mnater/Hyphenopoly). С этой библиотекой сначала проверяется поддержка расстановки переносов в самом браузере, и только потом под­гру­жа­ются библиотеки если поддержки в браузере нет.

В большинстве современных браузеров уже есть поддержка расстановки переносов слов при условии правильного указания кода языка. За это отвечают правила CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .hyphenate {
        hyphens: auto;
        -ms-hyphens: auto;
        -moz-hyphens: auto;
        -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    }
</style>
```

Язык указывается так:

```
<article lang="ru">
```