# В бд mysql есть куча символов \u00AD

Tags: mysql, utf-8, unicode

В БД MySQL есть куча скрытых символов.

Выделить их нельзя, но я узнал их код - `\u00AD`

Как их можно убрать?

Comment: А зачем их убирать?

Answer (score 1):

Это [символ мягкого переноса строки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81_(%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)#.D0.9C.D1.8F.D0.B3.D0.BA.D0.B8.D0.B9_.D0.BF.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.BE.D1.81). Явный аналог: `&shy;`

Этот символ указывает на места возможного переноса слов и используется для автома­ти­чес­кого переноса слов при отображении или печати. [Посмотреть, как это работает](https://codepen.io/sanmai/pen/gxVJpr), мож­но на стро­ке выше, или с таким правилом CSS на любом тексте:

```
.long-read {
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    -ms-hyphens: auto;
     hyphens: auto;
}
```

Обычно люди [ищут способы расставить такие символы переноса в текстах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/219994/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2), испо­льзуя воз­мож­ности офисных систем, или другие программы. Это  отдельная сложная задача! Вам эти символы достались просто так, бес­пла­тно. Удалить их можно, но лучше, чтобы для этого у вас была веская причина.

```
UPDATE `table` SET `field` = REPLACE(`field`, '\u00AD', '');
```